# Rewriting a formula in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, formula

So I am trying to rewrite the following formula to Obj-C (C):
[image]

```
double level = 10;
double xp = ((1/8 * level) * (level - 1)) + (75 * ( ((pow(2,(level - 1)/7)- 1) / (1 - pow(2, -1/7)))));
```

When I print it out I get `inf` meaning there is something wrong with how I've written the formula. I've re-written the thing many times for the past two hours - any help?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: its not the 1/8 being processed as an int is it?
Try putting a .0 after all your litterals (1.0/8.0) etc and see if that helps

Comment: @scb998 sorry about that. edited.

Comment: @matt yes, that was it! silly error on my part. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd worry about the sections "1/8" and "-1/7" being processed as ints and resulting with "0" in both cases.  Just putting a .0 after each literal tells the compiler (and fellow coders) to treat them as doubles

```
double xp = ((1.0/8.0 * level) * (level - 1.0)) + (75.0 * ( ((pow(2.0,(level - 1.0)/7.0)- 1.0) / (1.0 - pow(2.0, -1.0/7.0)))));
```